# Issue in generating code coverage report for exe instead of dll using OpenCover

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, opencover, reportgenerator

I have tried generating coverage report using OpenCover. It worked fine for DLLs but I have a console app that contains methods for which I have added a test project. For that, OpenCover is not generating a coverage report. Do I need to change the batch file? Below is the batch file with extra line-breaks for readability:

```
.\packages\OpenCover.4.6.519\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe 
    -register:user 
    "-filter:+[Mobile*]* -[Test*]* -[Mobile.Dummy.Test*]*" 
    "-target:.\packages\TestRunner.1.5.1\tools\TestRunner.exe" 
    "-targetargs:/noshadow .\Mobile.Test\bin\Debug\Mobile.Test.dll .\Mobile.Dummy.Test\bin\Debug\Mobile.Dummy.Test.dll"

.\packages\ReportGenerator.3.1.2\tools\ReportGenerator.exe 
    "-reports:results.xml" "-targetdir:.\coverage"
```

Comment: @shaun-wilde  Please have a look at this. Any help will be useful.

Comment: What does the xml output say about the .exe file?

Comment: @shaun-wilde exe is not included in xml. Although when i change output type to dll then it worked but still the issue is there for exe.

Comment: Interesting - do you have a sample project that replicates the issue?

Comment: I can't share my project but i can create another sample project with this issue. Where should i share?

Comment: OpenCover on github has an issues page.

Comment: Yup just logged an issue there. Will add sample project as well there.